# How can I get the height of the status bar in a samsung galaxy to use to set an Andengine camera's size?

Tags: android, size, andengine

I am using Andengine GLES2 in an app.  I am also using action bar sherlock with static attatchment, so I have my engine options like this:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    // Calculate ActionBar height
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    CAMERA_WIDTH = metrics.widthPixels;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels-mActionBarHeight;
    camera = new ZoomCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(false,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
```

The engine needs to run without full screen to allow the action bar to show.  This works perfectly with my Hp touchpad tablet, the entire game fills the space under the action bar.  When using a samsung galaxy S3, the top status bar isn't taken into account and the width looks too small because the height is bigger than it should be.  I need a way to get the height of the top status bar in my samsung galaxy somehow.  I have tried this method that I have seen in multiple threads on SO:

```
Rect rectgle= new Rect();
Window window= getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
int contentViewTop= 
    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int TitleBarHeight= contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;
```

This doesn't do anything.  I think it is working differently in the samsung galaxy than other devices because of that unique bar.  Does anyone know what I can do to get the height of this?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LayoutGameActivity.
in this find your width and height of rendersurfaceview and set your camera width and height.

```
public class YourGameActivity extends LayoutGameActivity{
     @Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
     // here find your LinearLayout width and height.
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutID() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
    return 0;
}
}
```